# T-SQL: How Can I Parse a JSON Array and Extract a Single Property Value?

Tags: arrays, json, t-sql

Given that:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY('[{"JobId":"2838","Options":1}, {"JobId":"2839","Options":1}]'))
```

Gives us:

```
key value                           type
0   {"JobId":"2838","Options":1}    5
1   {"JobId":"2839","Options":1}    5
```

---

How can I change my query to return the job ids?

```
value
2838
2839
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
SELECT JobId
FROM OPENJSON('[{"JobId":"2838","Options":1}, {"JobId":"2839","Options":1}]')
WITH (JobId INT N'$.JobId');
```